# Problem to delete table data in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I 'm trying to delete Excel table data by command

DELETE FROM [Phones_map$]

Then I got exception 
Additional information: Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM.

Here is connection string:
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=myfile.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=0"

Is another SQL command supported by Excel for table data deletion ?
I tried TRUNCATE table , but it does not supported
Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you're using an external data relationship, I'd suggest you that the correct approach to handle this data would be to import the data you need into a proper object / table / structure and then point your application to use this structure, rather than try to update the data directly in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but application will use DataTable or DataSet which should be afterwards to stored in the table , which is already existing . How can I tell that the existing data in table will be overwritten ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message gives you your answer - you can't delete the data.

Comment: I already found here [http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?s=d0adaf65eaea6cc4fc819340270658a9&p=969629#post969629](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?s=d0adaf65eaea6cc4fc819340270658a9&p=969629#post969629), there is problem to do it via sql query. So will try other ways . Thanks anyway for reply